# Delphi 10.2 - system exception – с переносом кода в библиотеку

Tags: delphi, activex

Есть следующий код который просто читает word файл и его сохраняет, а потом открывает – все хорошо работало.
Но после переноса строк кода (работы с документом word)

```
Words_Templs: variant;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

function CreateWord: boolean;
//create word application
begin
  CreateWord := true;
  try
    Words_Templs := CreateOleObject('Word.Application');
  except
    begin
//      showmessage('Пакет Microsoft Office не найден');
      Application.MessageBox('', 'Warning', MB_OK+MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
      CreateWord := false;
    end;
  end;
End;

function Open_Doc_Template(APath_file: string): boolean;
//open template file
var
  LDoc: variant;
begin
CreateWord;
  Open_Doc_Template := true;
  try
    LDoc := Words_Templs.Documents;
    LDoc.Open(APath_file);
  except
    Open_Doc_Template := false;
  end;
End;

function CloseDoc:boolean;
begin
  CloseDoc := true;
  try
    Words_Templs.ActiveDocument.Close;
  except
    CloseDoc := false;
  end;
end;

function Close_Document(AMode: integer): boolean; export;
{close document
0 - MS Word
1 - MS Excel}
begin
  if AMode = 0 then
  begin
    Close_Document := true;
    try
      Words_Templs.Quit;
      except
        Close_Document := false;
    end;
  end
end;

procedure OPEN_MAKE_DOC(ANamePath, ANameFile, ATypeFiles: string;
                        AMode: integer; var APathFile: string); export;
//open make document
{LNameFile - name file + extension file}
{LMode
0 - without open dialog window
1 - with open dialog window}
var
  handle: hwnd;
begin
  case AMode of
    0: shellexecute(handle,'open',pchar(ANamePath+'result_doc.rtf'),'','',1);
  end;
end;

function SaveDocAs(ANamePath, ANameFile: string; AOpenDoc: integer):boolean; export;
//save created doc
{
LOpenDoc
  0 - not open created doc
  1 - open created doc
}
var
  LPath: string;
begin
  SaveDocAs := true;
  try
    begin
      Words_Templs.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(ANamePath+'result_doc.rtf');
      CloseDoc;
      Close_Document(0);
      if AOpenDoc = 1 then
        OPEN_MAKE_DOC(ANamePath, 'result_doc.rtf', '', 0, LPath);
    end;
  except
    SaveDocAs := false;
  end;
end;
```

в библиотеку и закрытия приложения (вызвавшую dll) которое удачно прочитало и пересохранило файл, в режиме **ОТЛАДКИ**, стала возникать ошибка:

> Debugger Fault Notification
>   --------------------------- Project D:\Prog_Example\Example application\PEx_application.exe faulted with message: 'system
>   exception (code 0xc000000d) at 0x77417fdc'. Process Stopped. Use Step
>   or Run to continue.

Приложение (вызвавшее dll)

```
 procedure Open_Doc_Template(LPath_file: string); far; external 'SPF';
  function SaveDocAs(LNamePath, LNameFile: string;
                               LOpenDoc: integer):boolean; far; external 'SPF';

procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Open_Doc_Template(ExtractFileDir(application.ExeName)+'\Template\Template_example.rtf');
  SaveDocAs(ExtractFileDir(application.ExeName)+'\Result output\', 'result_doc.rtf', 1);
end;
```

В режиме простого запуска и закрытия приложения, после его закрытия, что-то секунду происходит конечно, но в конце концов все заканчивается удачно.

Что может быть не так?

Comment: Вы опять не включили в проекты приложения и библиотеки `SharedMem` первым юнитом. Что это за использование неинициализированного `handle` в `OPEN_MAKE_DOC`?

Comment: SharedMem - и в проекте (*Prdll.dpr*) и в вызывающем приложении (*PEx_application.dpr*) включены. Эта dll была под delphi7, и там я такой проблемы не видел.. Сейчас же у меня delphi 10.2

Comment: В какой версии Delphi откомпилирована DLL, и в какой - приложение?

Comment: Разобрался не совсем. Если эти функции в одном модуле библиотеки - то все работает. Но у меня все разбросано по двум модулям. **В первом модуле**: *CreateWord*, *Open_Doc_Template*, *CloseDoc*. **Во втором модуле**: *OPEN_MAKE_DOC*, *SaveDocAs*, *Close_Document*

Comment: т.е. поправка, если все функции в *dpr*, то все работает, А если в двух *pas*, то - ошибка

Comment: Кажется нашел проблему,
я в одном из модулей dll подключаю "Vcl.DBGrids;" - и когда я его подключаю возникает ошибка